Two squares inscribed inside a quarter circle determine the side length of the smaller square
I found a problem on the internet it's this:


Two squares are inscribed inside a quarter circle. The larger square has a 2 cm side length. Determine the second square’s side length.

I know the solution is the 7th problem of Educate Math's "10 Hard Geometry Math Problems For Circle" (via educatemath.com) but what are the other ways of doing it?
I just want a simpler, less complicated, much faster solution.
I tried using some basic properties of chord, symmetry, right angled triangle, but I felt like I was lost. I also tried using co-ordinate geometry but that was a mess.
Now, I am thinking about extending this figure to complete a full cicle then using some properties of chord to solve it.

You cite a perfectly good solution to the problem, but ask for others. Since you can only accept one response as "the" answer, please say something about the kinds of approaches that appeal to you most, and/or what you find unsatisfying about the cited solution's approach. If you're just curious about alternative solutions and want to compile a list, you can just say that ... but provide some motivation by explaining why this problem in particular has captured your interest. (Please add any context or clarification to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Yes, the solution is good but I'm curious to find other simple solutions.

"I'm curious to find other simple solutions." You'll want to define "simple". (Again, do this in the body of the question.) It would help to give your assessment of the cited soln; is it "simple"? are you looking for something simpler/less-simple? etc. ... The more you can say about what you're actually looking-for/interested-in, the better your chances of getting responses. (It's no fun to concoct, compose, format, and even illustrate a comprehensive solution only to have the asker say "I wanted something that avoided that technique" or, worse, "I already did it that way".) Good luck!

I thinking about  extending this figure to complete a full cicle then using some properties of chord to solve it.

That is literally the solution you link.  What properties would you want in a different solution here?

I found a solution but I am going to scool lemme post it after that

Observe that $PR$ is a radius of the circle and has length $2\sqrt{2}$ cm.  Let $x$ be the length of the edge of the smaller triangle.  Note that $PLM$ is a right triangle with leg lengths $2+x$ cm and $x$ cm and with hypotenuse the radius of the circle.  By the Pythagorean theorem,
\begin{align*}
8 \text{ cm}^2 &= (2+x)^2 + x^2 \text{ cm}^2  \\
    &= 4 + 4x + 2x^2\text{ cm}^2
\end{align*}
Solving $2(\hat{x}^2 + 2\hat{x} - 2) = 0$, we get $\hat{x} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4+8}}{2} = -1 \pm \sqrt{3}$.  Keeping the positive root, we have $x = -1  +\sqrt{3} \text{ cm}$.
